# how to fix MODULE NOT FOUND in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm building a discord bot with javascript with node module. after I run with node . command it says MODULE NOT FOUND. how do I fix this? :/

```
 import { Client } from 'discord.js';
const client = new Client();

const token = 'Token';

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('This Bot is Online!');
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Add more details to this question

Comment: Can you provide your code? Also, it's not a problem with VSCode. You haven't installed the module.

Comment: i installed the node.js

Comment: "name": "Discord Bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "megatron",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.1"
  }
}

Comment: Make sure the module is found :D

Comment: Thats the point, I can't find the module.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps in order, without skipping any.

1. From the command line, install the discord module

```sh
$ npm install discord.js
```

2. Run your script

```sh
$ node ./index.js
```

3. If it doesn't work, run this command to collect debugging info, and share the result with us:

```sh
$ less node_modules/discord.js/package.json | grep version
```

Comment: first it says that it cannot use import statement outside a module. debug says "Error: no test specified"

Comment: Oh, of course! If you're running this in node, you can't use `import` & `export`; you must use `require` and `module.exports =`. The former is called "ES6 modules," and it generally only works if you use transpilation tech. The latter is called "CommonJS," and it only works outside of browsers, so node/electron/react-native.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reinstall "discord.js" for every project or bot.

```
npm install discord.js
```